# How do I solve the following graph problem

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, connected-components

**The problem statement**

Given a directed graph of N nodes where each node is pointing to any one of the N nodes (can possibly point to itself). Ishu, the coder, is bored and he has discovered a problem out of it to keep himself busy. Problem is as follows:

A node is 'good' if it satisfies one of the following:

1. It is the special node (marked as node 1)
2. It is pointing to the special node (node 1)
3. It is pointing to a good node.
   Ishu is going to change pointers of some nodes to make them all 'good'. You have to find the minimum number of pointers to change in order to make all the nodes good (Thus, a Good Graph).

**NOTE**: Resultant Graph should hold the property that all nodes are good and each node must point to exactly one node.

**Problem Constraints**

1 <= N <= 10^5

**Input Format**

First and only argument is an integer array A containing N numbers all between 1 to N, where i-th number is the number of node that i-th node is pointing to.

**Output Format**

An Integer denoting minimum number of pointer changes.

**My Attempted Solution**

I tried building a graph by reversing the edges, and then trying to colour connected nodes, the answer would be `colors - 1`. In short , I was attempting to find number of connected components for a directed graph, which does not make sense(as directed graphs do not have any concept of connected components). Other solutions on the web like [this](https://discuss.codechef.com/t/interview-question-help-needed/18889/2) and [this](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5840928073842688) also point out to find number of connected components, but again connected components for aa directed graph does not make any sense to me. The question looks a bit trickier to me than a first look at it suggests.

Answer (score 1):

@mcdowella gives an accurate characterization of the graph -- in each connected component, all chains of pointers and up in the same dead end or cycle.

There's a complication if the special node has a non-null pointer, though.  If the special node has a non-null pointer, then it may or may not be in the terminal cycle for its connected component.  First set the special node pointer to null to make this problem go away, and then:

If the graph has *m* connected components, then *m-1* pointers would have to be changed to make all nodes good.

Since you don't have to actually change the pointers, all you need to do to solve the problem is count the connected components in the graph.

There are many ways to do this.  If you think of the edges as undirected, then you could use BFS or DFS to trace each connected component, for example.

With the kind of graph you actually have, though, where each node has a directed pointer, the easiest way to solve this is with a disjoint set data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Initially you just put each node in its own set, then union the sets on either side of each pointer, and then count the number of sets by counting the number of roots in the disjoint set structure.

If you haven't implemented a disjoint set structure before, it's a little tough to understand just how easy it is.  There are couple simple implementations here: [How to properly implement disjoint set data structure for finding spanning forests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004277/how-to-properly-implement-disjoint-set-data-structure-for-finding-spanning-fores/60008858)

Comment: Thanks for patching up the holes in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very similar question to [Graphic: Rerouting problem test in python language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630201/graphic-rerouting-problem-test-in-python-language/62631479#62631479). Because each node points to just one other node, your graph consists of a set of cycles (counting a node pointing to itself as a cycle) with trees feeding in to them. You can find a cycle by following pointers between nodes and checking for nodes that you have already visited. You need to break one link in each cycle, redirecting it to point to the special node. This routes everything else in that cycle, and all the trees that feed into it, to the special node.